# Query: Count of issues for specific test (snapshot of point in time)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to query a count of issues of a test that happened in the past. As a background, every year a test is done. A record is created for each "Issue" that comes up in each test. One test can have 0 to many issues. After the test is complete, those issues can be closed overtime when they're no longer issues. Each issue has a "current" status. There is also a table for tracking status changes on issues, like an audit log. When the next year comes around, the test would include any previous open issues and open additional issues. What is the correct query for finding how many issues are open in a specific test from year to year?

I.e:

- 2018 had 9 issues. 1 closed overtime.
- 2019 had 3 new issues plus the 8 still open from 2018.

Expected queries result to show 9 issues for 2018 and 11 issues for 2019.

The query below is what I have so far.

The relation of the tables are as follows.

- Engagements - Has one application
- Issues - One application can have    many issues
- Status Change - One issue can have many status changes

```
    SELECT *
        COUNT(*) as totalissues,              
        SUM(CASE WHEN issues.issue_type IN('EAPT','ENPT','ENVS') THEN 1 ELSE 0 
    end) AS externalissues,
        SUM(CASE WHEN issues.issue_type IN('IAPT','INPT','INVS') THEN 1 ELSE 0 
    end) AS internalissues     
         FROM engagements
         LEFT OUTER JOIN issues ON engagements.application_id = issues.application_id                   
         LEFT OUTER JOIN status_change sc1 ON issues.id = sc1.issue_id AND issues.engagement_id != engagements.engagement_id AND date(sc1.change_date) < date(engagements.end_date)           
         WHERE
            engagements.engagement_id = 'APT_ItemProcessingOutsourcing_DLM_2018_07'
            AND (       
            sc1.id is null                 
                or (                        
                   sc1.id = (
                       SELECT max(sc2.id)                                              
                       FROM engagements e2                                
                       LEFT OUTER JOIN issues i2 ON e2.application_id = i2.application_id                                
                       LEFT OUTER JOIN status_change sc2 ON                                 i2.id = sc2.issue_id                                     
                       AND date(sc2.change_date) < date(e2.end_date)                                
                       WHERE                                    
                       sc1.issue_id = sc2.issue_id                                   
                       AND sc2.change_date = (                                       
                             SELECT max(sc3.change_date)                                         
                             FROM status_change sc3                                                          
                             WHERE sc3.issue_id = sc2.issue_id                               
                             AND sc3.change_date <= date(e2.end_date)
                                )
                        )
                )
            AND sc1.new_status not in(4,8,9,10)
        );
```

This query has a count of 6 issues, I am expecting 9. Please let me know if you need more information.

```
Status change Table 
id  old_status  new_status  change_date issue_id    user_id comment_id
40748721    10  1   7/18/2017 15:09 14440592    64  NULL
67384812    1   3   7/26/2018 16:43 14440592    26  13023597
67384814    7   4   7/26/2018 16:44 14440592    26  13023599
67384813    3   7   7/26/2018 16:43 14440592    26  13023598
40748722    10  1   7/18/2017 15:09 14440593    64  NULL
40748724    10  1   7/18/2017 15:09 14440595    64  NULL
40748725    10  1   7/18/2017 15:09 14440596    64  NULL
40748723    10  1   7/18/2017 15:09 14440594    64  NULL
67383070    1   3   7/26/2018 14:15 14440594    26  13023588
67383078    7   4   7/26/2018 14:16 14440594    26  13023590
67383074    3   7   7/26/2018 14:15 14440594    26  13023589
40748726    10  1   7/18/2017 15:09 14440597    64  NULL
40748727    10  1   7/18/2017 15:09 14440598    64  NULL
40748728    10  1   7/18/2017 15:09 14440599    64  NULL
40748729    10  1   7/18/2017 15:09 14440600    64  NULL
71206458    10  1   8/27/2018 11:46 23900484    26  NULL
71206459    10  1   8/27/2018 11:46 23900485    26  NULL
112852911   10  1   5/24/2019 5:07  800002498   99  NULL
112852912   10  1   5/24/2019 5:07  800002499   99  NULL
112852913   10  1   5/24/2019 5:07  800002500   99  NULL
112852914   10  1   5/24/2019 5:07  800003019   99  NULL
92704214    3   2   3/22/2019 9:39  14440593    80  16533839
92704217    3   2   3/22/2019 9:39  14440595    80  16533842
92704218    3   2   3/22/2019 9:39  14440596    80  16533843
92704219    3   2   3/22/2019 9:39  14440597    80  16533844
92704215    3   2   3/22/2019 9:39  14440598    80  16533840
92704216    3   2   3/22/2019 9:39  14440599    80  16533841
92704220    3   2   3/22/2019 9:39  14440600    80  16533845
93598047    3   2   3/24/2019 9:51  23900484    80  16548757
77165368    3   2   10/22/2018 14:28    23900485    64  14221198
93598048    3   2   3/24/2019 9:51  23900485    80  16548758
92654993    1   3   3/21/2019 1:00  14440593    1   16531378
92654994    1   3   3/21/2019 1:00  14440595    1   16531379
121160006   2   3   6/20/2019 1:00  14440595    1   17411641
92654995    1   3   3/21/2019 1:00  14440596    1   16531380
121160007   2   3   6/20/2019 1:00  14440596    1   17411642
92654996    1   3   3/21/2019 1:00  14440597    1   16531381
92654997    1   3   3/21/2019 1:00  14440598    1   16531382
92654998    1   3   3/21/2019 1:00  14440599    1   16531383
102075451   2   3   4/24/2019 8:53  14440599    99  16875917
92654999    1   3   3/21/2019 1:00  14440600    1   16531384
92655000    1   3   3/21/2019 1:00  23900484    1   16531385
102075453   2   3   4/24/2019 8:55  23900484    99  16875919
75968834    1   3   10/13/2018 1:00 23900485    1   14157115
92655001    2   3   3/21/2019 1:00  23900485    1   16531386
122784894   3   4   6/26/2019 7:40  14440595    99  17548826
122784893   3   4   6/26/2019 7:40  14440596    99  17548825
112836464   7   4   5/23/2019 23:51 14440599    80  17238673
112836465   7   4   5/23/2019 23:52 23900484    80  17238674
102075452   3   7   4/24/2019 8:54  14440599    99  16875918
102075455   3   7   4/24/2019 8:56  23900484    99  16875921
```

```
Engagement example
engagement_id                            application_id start_date  end_date
APT_ItemProcessingOutsourcing_DLM_2018_07   735         7/16/2018   7/26/2018
```

```
Issues example
id  created issue_type  status_id   application_id   engagement_id
14440592    2017-07-18 15:09:09 EAPT    4   735     APT_ItemProcessingOutsourcing_DLM_2017_03
14440593    2017-07-18 15:09:09 EAPT    2   735     APT_ItemProcessingOutsourcing_DLM_2017_03
14440594    2017-07-18 15:09:10 EAPT    4   735     APT_ItemProcessingOutsourcing_DLM_2017_03
14440595    2017-07-18 15:09:10 EAPT    4   735     APT_ItemProcessingOutsourcing_DLM_2017_03
14440596    2017-07-18 15:09:10 EAPT    4   735     APT_ItemProcessingOutsourcing_DLM_2017_03
14440597    2017-07-18 15:09:10 EAPT    2   735     APT_ItemProcessingOutsourcing_DLM_2017_03
14440598    2017-07-18 15:09:10 EAPT    2   735     APT_ItemProcessingOutsourcing_DLM_2017_03
14440599    2017-07-18 15:09:10 EAPT    4   735     APT_ItemProcessingOutsourcing_DLM_2017_03
14440600    2017-07-18 15:09:10 EAPT    2   735     APT_ItemProcessingOutsourcing_DLM_2017_03
23900484    2018-08-27 11:46:38 EAPT    4   735     APT_ItemProcessingOutsourcing_DLM_2018_07
23900485    2018-08-27 11:46:38 EAPT    2   735     APT_ItemProcessingOutsourcing_DLM_2018_07
800002498   2019-05-24 05:07:28 EAPT    1   735     APT_ItemProcessingOutsourcing_DLM_2019_04
800002499   2019-05-24 05:07:28 EAPT    1   735     APT_ItemProcessingOutsourcing_DLM_2019_04
800002500   2019-05-24 05:07:28 EAPT    1   735     APT_ItemProcessingOutsourcing_DLM_2019_04
800003019   2019-05-24 05:07:28 EAPT    1   735     APT_ItemProcessingOutsourcing_DLM_2019_04
```

Comment: please add the table in text form, so that help can test their ideas..

Comment: I've added the 3 tables being referenced now.

Comment: your table issues is missing issues.engagement_id

Comment: I've added the engagement id to the issues now. You can see which issues below to which year/test by the year at the end.

Comment: As far as i can tell there are no Data in status_change that fits any criteria. I tried a lot of combinations, but the dates don't fit at all. So update your question, so that i can find any data that fit. here are the data to play with https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=45ecc8a86092b2de4aba69db92803e60

Comment: So the issue id's that i need to exclude are any that were closed (status id 4) before the engagement completed testing. The status id in the issues table is showing the current status. The issue status table shows the history of changes. The goal is to pinpoint what issues where not in status of 4 during the test.

Comment: The problern as you can see in the example is, i get 2 Ids 23900484   and 23900485. Both appear 5 Times each not 6 . Last there are Both all over the date place, so i can't really reduced it to one of them without knowing exactly witch to choose. the Date doesn't relate as far as i can see. Use my first select and see if you dpn't have a determenistic way to reduce them. maybe a time frame. is he a good cause, why you don't save the actual date for reference